# intellij pycharm/python : failed to create JVM. JVM - path:C:\Program Files\ JetBrains\ PyCharm 2020.1.2\jbr\

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

Error message window display image:
[image]

```
If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a java_home variable in Computer > system properties > system settings > environment variables. 
Failed to create JVM. JVM path: C:\Program Files\ JetBrains\ PyCharm 2020.1.2\jbr\
```

Why my Pycharm IDE cannot be opened, and the JVM path: *C:\Program Files\ JetBrains\ PyCharm 2020.1.2\jbr* appears in the window. What is the reason?

I have searched on the Internet and discussed that the environment variable has not been established, but I have established it (as shown in the figure below). What are the reasons for the conflict?

The following is my environment variable settings images.

User variables:

pycharm User variables
[image]

path User variables
[image]

System variable:

classpath System variable
[image]

JAVA_HOME System variable
[image]

path System variable
[image]

Reference material: https://www.arulraj.net/2014/10/fix-pycharm-failed-to-create-jvm.html
I have found something similar, but I don’t understand it. I hope I can give some explanations and your suggestions.

Comment: Additional supplements due to various reasons
[Error message window display image][1]
UserＶariables:
[pycharm User variables image][2]
[path User variables image][3]
[Error message window display image][1]
SystemＶariable:
[classpath System variable image][4]
[JAVA_HOME System variable image][5]
[path System variable image][6]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0cyC.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlflv.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLrtK.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mUWJ.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54kL.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWQFw.png

Comment: >>> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/srYp9sJk5C/ <<<

If you think the layout is messy, you can click this version to watch, and open the picture for review according to the number.
intellij pycharm/python: failed to create JVM.

Comment: pycharm64.exe.vmoptions file : 
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true

Comment: pycharm64.exe.vmoptions file context :  https://imgur.com/lVAa7KA

Comment: java -version:
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

javac -version: javac 15.0.2

Comment: Edit your question with more data, rather than adding a bunch of comments to do so.

Comment: vmoptions文件裡的最後一行應該是
-javaagent:D:\PyCharm 2019.3.3\bin\jetbrains-agent.jar
javaagent命令後面應該跟一個:而不是空格
順便整理一下看到的所有解決辦法

環境變量問題
編譯器問題（下JDK加JAVA_HOME環境變量）
上次卸載有殘留導致裝不上
vmoptions文件內部問題（減小xx數值）

最後總結就是直接刪除IDE重灌解決不必要問題，還有是因為-javaagent:D:\PyCharm 2019.3.3\bin\jetbrains-agent.jar卡到。

Comment: Please run using idea.bat, do you see any details in the console?

Does it help if you delete the custom .vmoptions file located in the config directory? See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519 .